# How to correctly use Ember.required in a Mixin

Tags: ember.js

I try to use Ember.required but I might be doing something wrong.

Why is this JSBin not shouting something about the missing foo property on the bar Object ?

http://jsbin.com/oHELUBEs/1/edit?html,js,console

Comment: This is a bug https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1299

Comment: Ah, thank you for the link Marcio